# conditional statement in pandas Not working

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to check for the value and assign the data to `new_col` using pandas if condition. But getting ValueError even I tried multiple ways.

Code:

```
df['new_col'] = np.where((df.rec_type == 'ABC' or df.rec_type == 'XYZ'), df.col1, df.col2)
```

Error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

**Note:** `rec_type` has other values to including nulls.

Comment: please show an example of your input & output dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
np.where(((df.rec_type == 'ABC') | (df.rec_type == 'XYZ')), df.col1, df.col2)
```

It gets confused about the logical order in which you mean things. This fixes it.